# Unable create tc server instance on sts 4

Tags: ide, spring-tool-suite, tcserver

Creating server from server window in sts gives me this error. I am choosing base template to create server. I also tried using cmd with admin rights, still same error.

Error Details:create command failed. String runtimes not valid version format. Expected ,,[.patch][.release]

Reason: Error creating server instance with command:
D:\Users\pivotal location..\tcserver.bat create server -v runtimes -t base --property base.runtime.user=null --java-home C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_191. Check access permission for the directory D:\Users\pivotal location.. and its files and subdirectories.

Can't share the picture didn't have reputation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Pivotal tc Server installation sits in a read-only location on your disc or with limited write permissions. I would recommend to install tc-Server into a directory where you have full permissions, configure that install in STS, and try again. That should help.

Comment: No there is no such restriction. It is my personal pc and i've checked all permissions.

Comment: what happens if you create a server instance manually from the command line using tcserver.bat?

Comment: Same error (Error Details:create command failed. String runtimes not valid version format. Expected ,,[.patch][.release])

Comment: sounds like it is a more general issue with creating instances using tc-server, therefore I added a tag for tcserver to the question above.

Answer (score 0):

You will get ahead if you provide a proper tc runtime version at the -v option. E.g. if you have the tc runtime tomcat-9.0.12.A.RELEASE installed, take ["9.0.12.A.RELEASE" as runtime version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaCfJ.png).

Unfortunately you will not be out of the woods by doing so. Although a server instance will be created, there will be another error message: "The specified server is not valid. The .tc-runtime-instance file is missing.". There will be a .tc-runtime-instance-file in your instance-dir, but without any content. That's the point where I am currently sticking.